# Bash does not print any error msg upon non-existing commands starting with dot

Tags: linux, bash

This is really just out of curiosity.

A typo made me notice that in Bash, the following:

```
$ .anything
```

does not print any error ("anything" not to be interpreted literally, it can really be anything, and no space after the dot).

I am curious about how this is interpreted in bash.

Note that `echo $?` after such command returns 127. This usually means "command not found". It does make sense in this case, however I find it odd that no error message is printed.

Why would `$ anything` actually print `bash:anything: command not found...` (assuming that no `anything` cmd is in the PATH), while `$ .anything` slips through silently?

System: Fedora Core 22

Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.3.39(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

**EDIT:**

Some comments below indicated the problem as non-reproducible at first.

The answer of @hek2mgl below summarises the many contributions to this issue, which was eventually found (by @n.m.) as reproducible in FC22 and submitted as a bug report in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1292531

Comment: I get `-bash: .anything: command not found`, can you do `type .anything`

Comment: `$ type .anything
-bash: type: .anything: not found`

Comment: I agree, this is not reproducible.

Comment: Voting to close on this basis

Comment: Interesting that it isn't reproducible. I'm running a very standard FC22. Nothing against closing it (although I don't understand the downvoting, the question seems valid to me)

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be reproducible (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this is sensible to prevent noise due to questions arising from systems that could be in heck knows what state, but to be entirely fair, in a way it is valid, because if that's what your shell is doing then there remains the question of why. Unless you get lucky through someone making a good guess though, no one will be able to answer you because no one else has this feature.

Comment: You could try and strace a shell and see if anything interesting is revealed.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `.anything`, as you won't be able to see it with normal `ls` ?

Comment: @123 that should still lead to "command not found"

Comment: @Michael Fair enough. Just for completeness, I do not get it on one system only, but on all FC systems in our lan (about 10 systems among desktops/servers). All plain FC22.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Not if it has permission to run and the directory is in path

Comment: @123 oh, yeah, but OP said `Note that echo $? after such command returns 127. This usually means "command not found".`. It's as if the error message is omitted.

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah that is weird, just covering the bases.

Comment: @123 on ubuntu even an executable will give an error, you'd need `./.anything` (I just checked).

Comment: @AndrasDeak not if it is in your $PATH

Comment: @123 OK, I give up:D

Comment: @AndrasDeak Although that depends on the PATH config, this is exactly why Stack Overflow asks for reproducible questions, it rapidly becomes a nightmare to untangle possibilities and counter possibilities.

Comment: @comuz could anyone have tampered with your system (since you mentioned the same behaviour over the whole LAN)? If it's a sorta-public thing, someone might have messed it up for reasons.

Comment: @AndrasDeak no, I'd exclude that.

Comment: And is the message also missing if you use a non-existing command without a dot?

Comment: To be clear: I do not wish to waste people's time on an ill-defined problem, if this is one. I do not expect anyone to have the answer in their pockets and also this does not seem like a real issue. More of a curiosity. Any suggestion on *how* to get closer to why this is not reproducible would be of interest to me, but again: more in academic terms than anything else.

Comment: @AndrasDeak no, without a dot I do get the error message

Comment: @cornuz put it a script and run strace on it to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Since none of us seem to reproduce this on different systems, you might try some unrelated users of FC22. If they can reproduce it: it's a legit bug that should be tracked. If they can't: it's more likely to be a quirk related to a space-time distortion around your workplace, or sunspots.

Comment: @cornuz: Can you run `bash -x .anything` and see what output you get?

Comment: @anubhava : `bash: .anything: No such file or directory`

Comment: @anubhava Then again `bash .anything` probably gives the same error...

Comment: @cornuz please tell me you're not putting a space between the dot and `anything`: that is how you source a file in bash... But you *are* putting a space between the dot and `dotbug` in your edit #2.

Comment: Since your script doesn't read .bashrc, it is not exposed to things normally set in .bashrc. Like e.g. `command_not_found_handle`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak no, no space between dot and anything. The space is between dot and dotbug, which is a file that contains `.anything`. The space there was intentinal

Comment: @cornuz so it gives the error message if it is inside a script but not off the command line ?

Comment: @cornuz OK, you had me worried there for a second;) But you're right, I misunderstood your intentions, sorry. Makes sense now. So what's the exact difference between "executing through sourcing" (->no error message) and "executing through ./" (->error message). Is it really `.bashrc`?

Comment: @123 Almost. `. script` (or `source script`) behaves the same as cmdline (which makes sense). But the script run by a bash invocation runs as expected (it prints error)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I doubt it's my `.bashrc` (which I checked anyway) because the same happens with root, which has an untouched `.bashrc` (i.e., it only loads `/etc/bashrc`)

Comment: Related: [difference between sourcing and executing](http://superuser.com/a/176788). Is it possible that a different kind of shell is used in the two cases? Or only environmental variables are different? You're not accessing the system through SSH, but rather locally, right?

Comment: It actually should be in `/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh`.

Comment: Yep, it is related to this script indeed. If I do `unset -f command_not_found_handle`, as hek2mgl suggests in his answer below, the error message pops up again.

Comment: My own conclusion would be that the executable `/usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found` that is installed in my systems is buggy (see last edit in the question). It should deal consistently with both `.anything` and `anything`. Thank you for throwing all your thoughts into this, I believe it wasn't a completely useless exercise.

Comment: I think this was useful, I'm pretty sure `pk-command-not-found` should not be doing what it's doing (see the comment of @n.m. below). But I believe you should change the question title: it's very misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash supports a handler for situations when a command can't be found. You can define the following function:

```
function command_not_found_handle() {
    command=$1
    # do something
}
```

Using that function it is possible to suppress the error message. Search for that function in your bash startup files.

Another way to find that out is to unset the function. Like this:

```
$ unset -f command_not_found_handle
$ .anything # Should display the error message
```

After some research, @n.m. found out that the described behaviour is by intention. FC22 implements `command_not_found_handle` and calls the program `/etc/libexec/pk-command-not-found`. This program is part of the PackageKit project and will try to suggest installable packages if you type a command name that can't be found.

In it's main() function the program explicitly checks if the command name starts with a dot and silently returns in that case. This behaviour was introduced in this commit:

https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/commit/0e85001b

as a response to this bug report:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1151185

IMHO this behaviour is questionable. At least other distros are not doing so. But now you know that the behaviour is 100% reproducible and you may follow up on that bug report.

Comment: I believe it's due to the lack of this being an answer. It's more like a comment, and formatted comments are customary to be CW. (I'm only guessing, I didn't vote, but I'd understand this.)

Comment: What? What is it then? I explained clearly how it can happen that no message appears on screen. If you don't believe that, try it!

Comment: I believe there are several reasons why this can happen. What if stderr is redirected? What if little gnomes ate the message? I'm just saying that even you yourself don't seem to be convinced that this is the problem. It's *a possible one*. Guesswork belongs to the comments, in my opinion.

Comment: How should the error get redirected, the OP told he types `$ .anything`  (Note the prompt, it would not getting displays if the shell has been started with errors redirected to /dev/null). The situation that a little gnome ate the message is very unlikely. That instead `command_not_found_handle` is being used is pretty likely.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point about the display. And anyway, all of the possible scenarios seem wildly improbable (like the `command-not-found` script failing: why would it do that? And why on a dot?). And any-anyway, I wasn't trying to prove that you're wrong (because I have no clue what's happening), only tried to explain the downvotes. My comments have 2 votes and you have two downvotes, so it might be that the downvoters are closer to my opinion than yours.

Comment: @AndrasDeak There is no requirement for an answer to be exhaustive.

Comment: @n.m. There is a requirement for it to not be speculation though.

Comment: @123 Where is this requirement listed? How an answer to this question can be not speculative? If such a requirement exist it certainly needs to be dropped, as it makes many valid questions unanswerable.

Comment: @n.m. for what it's worth, I frequently see "Try doing this and that" kind of answers presumably flagged as NAA. Don't know about actual regulations/norms.

Comment: @n.m. It can't be non speculative, that's the point. Don't answer if there isn't one. Why don't i just write an answer with random excerpts from the kernel, they might be involved somehow ?

Comment: It's a question for someone to post on meta isn't it really, if it hasn't been already - there is a bit of a fine line, but I have to say I do tend to agree there is a very definite limit to the speculative quotient of a answer. I'd say a guess shouldn't be an answer but some speculation is ok, or a lot of useful answers would be eliminated.

Comment: @n.m. no official help or meta.SO, but there's [a post on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127900). Possibly not the same, these questions usually come up with unclear questions (rather than unclear problems).

Comment: The revised answer is actually a lot better, and to the point, and it looks to me like you could reproduce the question symptoms by `function command_not_found_handle() { return 127 }` now. It would however occur for ALL shell commands, not just those beginning with a period.

Comment: @Michael On a vanilla Fedora, yes. However, on a vanilla Fedora the message would not being suppressed at all. At the end we don't know what the OP configured. I would like to hear if `unset -f command_not_found_handle` fixes the problem for the OP.

Comment: `At the end we don't what the OP configured.`, so why have you answered ? `I would like to hear if unset -f command_not_found_handle`, ask that in a comment then instead of posting a speculative answer.

Comment: @123 Tricky though, I was pretty unimpressed with the first version of the answer, and I more agree than disagree with you, but now it's been completely rewritten a couple of times I'm sitting on the fence a bit; the answer isn't really offending me.

Comment: @123 command_not_found_handle is known to have problems on stock FC, thus it is reasonably likely that it is involved. If you know about a kernel configuration that is also reasonably likely to produce such results, you are invited to write it as an answer.

Comment: By default command_not_found_handle calls /etc/libexec/default. pk-command-not-found program. I have looked at the source. It contains this statement near the beginning of `main()`: `if (argv[1][0] == '.') goto out;` I think we can declare the mystery solved,

Comment: @n.m. that's a pretty weird piece of code. Anyway, I think you should add an answer (and maybe a bugreport?:)

Comment: Sorry messed up the previous comment, the pass should be  `/etc/libexec/pk-command-not-found`.

Comment: @hek2mgl Indeed, unsetting `command_not_found_handle` function I do get the "command not found output"

Comment: @hek2mgl You changed your answer about 5 times, your original "answer" was appalling which is why all us "fools" were "arguing" with you.

Comment: @n.m. Nice! If you feel like writing into an answer what you found in the source code of `/etc/libexec/pk-command-not-found`, I'll accept it. It was really a collaborative effort, but you got to the actual cause.